# Combining two queries (MS SQL)

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables

One table connects "client ID" with "product id"

```
TABLE A

ClientID    ProductID
1       2
1       4
1       6
2       3
2       5
```

Then there is another table that logs the amount of time spent with a product:

```
TABLE B
ProductID   Time    Date_added  
2       10  (datetime)
4       2   (datetime)
2       3   (datetime)
4       1   (datetime)
```

How do I combine two queries:

One query to get all the product id's associated with a client

```
SELECT ProductID FROM TABLE_A where ClientID = 1
```

Then get a monthly sum of all the time spent with those products?

```
SELECT SUM(time) from Table_B WHERE DATEPART(month, Date_added) = 8 AND ProductID = (products from the previous query?)
```

Comment: time is not a column in Table_A

Comment: @olivehour Good catch, I didn't even check that at first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want a join statement, taking a shot in the dark but probably

```
  SELECT A.ClientID,SUM(B.Time)
  FROM
    TABLE A AS A
  LEFT JOIN 
    TABLE B AS B ON (A.ProductID = B.ProductID)
  WHERE
    DATEPART(month, B.Date_added) = 8
  GROUP BY
    A.ClientID
```

This will show the total of time for all products as grouped by the Client ID. This will also include clients that did not have any time spent on products for the month

Answer (score 0):

You're really very close.

```
SELECT SUM(B.time)
FROM Table_B B INNER JOIN
     Table_A A ON B.ProductID = A.ProductID
WHERE DATEPART(month, B.Date_added) = 8
  AND A.ClientID = 1
;
```

Comment: To to SUM(), don't you have to have a GROUP BY clause?

Comment: @olivehour Not if it's the only column being returned, which is how the OP had written the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(time) from Table_B 

WHERE DATEPART(month, Date_added) = 8 
AND ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID FROM TABLE_A where ClientID = 1)
```

- Updated to use IN instead of =

Comment: @Yuck JOIN could potentially return multiple records if ProductID is not unique. Not likely I know, given how the question is described, but these things happen.

Comment: @potNPan ...re-read the question. The OP **wants** multiple products. There's no problem with there being multiple products in the summation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(time)
FROM B
Join A on A.productID = B.ProductID
WHERE where a.clientID =1
group my month(b.date);
```